# Ridding a JFrame of the current shape. i.e Clearing the "canvas" such as in Microsoft Paint

Tags: java, graphics, jframe, actionlistener, jmenuitem

To resolve this particular issue is to be able to get rid of the current shape in the JFrame. I just finished the Joyce Farrel book on Java, so I decided to challenge myself to create this mini app, but I'm stuck on getting this shape to disappear. I tore out the rest of the code not related to the issue to make the question easier to answer. I still added the entire project to the end for those of you who maybe want to look a tad bit more in depth, or perhaps it may help see to a solution.

To clarify, the first pasted code segment is where I believe the issue resides. The second pasted segment is everything I have put together up to this point. If the issue is clear, I would appreciate not spoiling this learning experience for me by telling me the answer if it is indeed a very simple solution. I will keep looking for the simple solution in hopes of retaining more information during my own research. Simply give me an area in which to research on java. Hope this helps!!!

While the application is running, the user selects the JMenuItem "New Canvas" and the application freezes suddenly? It doesn't crash, but freezes the entire JFrame, forcing the user to close the JFrame and begin anew with the application. Ideally, when the user selects the "New Canvas" option, the shape in the center of the JFrame would disappear, but unfortunately all the shape does is linger all the while the application freezes. What I'm assuming is that as soon as I get rid of the shape, it immediately comes back because of the paintComponent() method and causes the application to freeze.

Tried ----
1.) **I've called the repaint() method as well as the validate() method as the actions to perform when the JMenuItem is pressed**

2.) **I've tried commenting out the call to super in the paintComponent() method and did receive rather neat results, however it did not resolve the issue**

3.) **I've tried instantiating a Graphics object from the beginning of the class, then creating a method which accepts the Graphics object and casts it to be of Graphics2D, which will then draw a simple square in the center of the JFrame**[Error from this attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soGaU.png)

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at JHouse.draw(JHouse.java:73)
        at JHouse.actionPerformed(JHouse.java:123)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

**Here is the shortened code containing the main issue of the shape not properly disappearing:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JHouse extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, ActionListener {

   private boolean isPressed;
   // Menus/Panel

   private static JFrame frame;
   private static JMenuBar mainBar = new JMenuBar();
   private static JMenu create = new JMenu("Create");
   private static JMenuItem canvas = new JMenuItem("New Canvas");

   // Locations/Sizes (Tools)
   private static int JSize = 700;
   private int rectXLoc = 200;
   private int rectYLoc = 200;
   private int rectXSize = 300;
   private int rectYSize = 300;

   public static void createJFrame() {

      frame = new JFrame();
      frame.add(new JHouse());
      frame.setLocation(650, 225);
      frame.setSize(JSize, JSize);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setJMenuBar(mainBar);
      mainBar.add(create);
      create.add(canvas);
      frame.add(new JHouse(), "Center");
   }

   public JHouse() {

     canvas.addActionListener(this);
     addMouseListener(this);
     addMouseMotionListener(this);
   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

      super.paintComponent(g);
      BasicStroke aStroke = new BasicStroke(1.0f,
         BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND);
      Graphics2D gr2D = (Graphics2D)g;
      gr2D.setStroke(aStroke);
      gr2D.drawRect(rectXLoc, rectYLoc, rectXSize, rectYSize);
   }

   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

   }

   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

      isPressed = true;
   }

   public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

      int x = e.getX();
      int y = e.getY();

      if(isPressed){
         rectXLoc = x;
         rectYLoc = y;
         repaint();
         validate();     
      }
   }

   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

      isPressed = false;
   }

   public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
   }

   public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
   }

   public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

      Object source = e.getSource();

      if(source == canvas) {
         frame.removeAll();
         frame.repaint();
         frame.validate();
      }
   }

   public static void main(String [] args) {

      createJFrame();
   }
}
```

**Here is the complete code for the project I am currently undertaking:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JHouse extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, ActionListener {

   //Graphics g;  This was part of attempt # 3 (Failed attempt)

   private boolean isPressed;

   // Menus/Panel
   private static JFrame frame;
   private static JMenuBar mainBar = new JMenuBar();
   private static JMenu create = new JMenu("Create");
   private static JMenu presets = new JMenu("Presets");
   private static JMenu transform = new JMenu("Transform");
   private static JMenu tools = new JMenu("Tools");
   private static JMenuItem canvas = new JMenuItem("New Canvas");
   private static JMenuItem freeDraw = new JMenuItem("Free Draw");
   private static JMenuItem rectangle = new JMenuItem("Rect Tool");
   private static JMenuItem polygon = new JMenuItem("Polygon Tool");
   private static JMenuItem circle = new JMenuItem("Circular Tool");

   // Locations/Sizes (Tools)
   private static int JSize = 700;
   private int rectXLoc = 200;
   private int rectYLoc = 200;
   private int rectXSize = 300;
   private int rectYSize = 300;

   public static void createJFrame() {

      frame = new JFrame();
      frame.add(new JHouse());
      frame.setLocation(650, 225);
      frame.setSize(JSize, JSize);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setJMenuBar(mainBar);
      mainBar.add(create);
      mainBar.add(tools);
      mainBar.add(presets);
      create.add(canvas);
      tools.add(freeDraw);
      tools.add(rectangle);
      tools.add(polygon);
      tools.add(circle);
   }

   public JHouse() {

     canvas.addActionListener(this);
     freeDraw.addActionListener(this);
     rectangle.addActionListener(this);
     polygon.addActionListener(this);
     circle.addActionListener(this);
     addMouseListener(this);
     addMouseMotionListener(this);
   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

      super.paintComponent(g);
      BasicStroke aStroke = new BasicStroke(1.0f,
         BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND);
      Graphics2D gr2D = (Graphics2D)g;
      gr2D.setStroke(aStroke);
      gr2D.drawRect(rectXLoc, rectYLoc, rectXSize, rectYSize);
   }

  /* public void draw(Graphics g) {
      BasicStroke aStroke = new BasicStroke(1.0f,
         BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND);        This was a part of attempt # 3 (Failed attempt)
      Graphics2D gr2D = (Graphics2D)g;
      gr2D.setStroke(aStroke);
      gr2D.drawRect(rectXLoc, rectYLoc, rectXSize, rectYSize);
   }*/

   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

      /* rectXSize += 6;
      repaint();
      validate();*/
   }
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

      isPressed = true;
   }

   public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

      int x = e.getX();
      int y = e.getY();

      if(isPressed){
         rectXLoc = x;
         rectYLoc = y;
         repaint();
         validate();     
      }
   }

   public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
   }

   public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
   }

   public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
   }

   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

      isPressed = false;
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

      Object source = e.getSource();

      if(source == canvas) {
         frame.removeAll();
         frame.repaint();  
         frame.validate();
         //draw(g);    This was part of attempt #3 (Failed attempt)

      }
   }
   public static void main(String [] args) {

      createJFrame();
   }
}
```

Comment: I'd careful of using `JFrame#removeAll` as it will also remove the `JRootPane` which is controlling the menu bars and content pane

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're trying to do but if you're making a "paint" program the thing to do is just clear the canvas to all white.  If you're tracking your "shapes" use an ArrayList and just `clear()` that.

Comment: I think, before you go any further, you really, really need to have a read through [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) to better understand how painting actually works

Comment: To be fair, the homework assignment was to create a simple house using java.. I got a little curious and really wanted to create something neat.. Sorry for wasting your time. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `frame.removeAll()` method removes all the components in the frame. Including your menus, which is why you are getting a null pointer exception. A solution here would be to reset the initial values set here using a private method. 
For example:

```
private void resetValues() {
    JSize = 700;   
    rectXLoc = 200;
    rectYLoc = 200;
    rectXSize = 300;
    rectYSize = 300;
}
```

use this method to reset the values to the initial values and then call this method instead of `frame.removeAll()`. So your condition would be:

```
if(source == canvas) {
     resetValues();
     frame.repaint();  
     frame.validate();
}
```

Here you can use this method to reset the values of all the operations. I see that you have 4 different operations available - Free draw, Rectangle, Polygon and Circle. You need to reset all the values.

If you need an empty canvas (i.e. you want all the components inside it, to be removed), declare a boolean variable, say `boolean reset = false` as a class variable and in the `paintComponent()` method have a check :

```
if(reset) {
   reset = false; // you dont want reset to be set true permanantly
   return;
}
// rest of your code
```

and in the `actionPerformed()` method, before calling `frame.repaint()` set `reset = true`. This would repaint the component. but nothing will be painted so you will get an empty canvas.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That helps me tremendously! You have resolved my issue!